# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on ASP.NET MVC API local website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

Recently I had to reset windows on my work laptop due to a faulty driver that caused endless bluescreens after a few minutes of booting up. I use windows 10, and had windows on its own partition so all my work was unaffected by the reset.

This is relevant because before the reset, my ASP.NET sites would run perfectly fine locally with IIS 10, I could run my API site and use Postman to do HTTP requests as expected, login to a localized version of the site, etc. All without issues. After the reset, and the subsequent reinstalling of all the programs that were present before the reset, the API site no longer works as expected. Now I get a consistent 403.14 Forbidden error on the main page, and various other errors depending on whats being done.

I need to clarify that this site is not a directory site so enabling directory browsing as most answers to this questions tell to do is not the solution I need.

I've tried dozens of solutions both on SO and elsewhere, including:

-Making sure the IIS app pool is set to v4.0 and not v2.0

-Typing this: 'C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i'
in CMD.

-Making sure all the required features in 'turn windows features on/off' are on.

-Putting this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

in the config.

-Trying this alternative to the above:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
```

-Resetting all the repositories for the sites with a hard reset in git, then cleaning and rebuilding everything

-Checking with my coworker that both of our setups are the same, including all the important files and program settings (they are, his local sites work as expected)

-Reinstalling windows again and installing all the programs with great attention to what does what and what order they're installed in.

-Testing that it all works on my personal PC (it does)

The expected result is that the home page is a blank white page, and each of the controllers accessed from there (i.e. http://localhost/api.mysite/account/login/, .../account/getinfo/,.../account/changeinfo/) all work as expected accepting and returning json. The only error messages are as follows:

403.14 when attempting to access the site through a browser to the default page (http://localhost/api.mysite/)

405 error when POST-ing to the default page with Postman, as expected(?).

404 error when trying to POST or GET to any of the controllers methods in the API site with Postman. (http://localhost/api.mysite/account/login etc.)

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is incredibly frustrating! Thank you.

Comment: Visual Studio Tool >> Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Path>> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.
>> Run the aspnet_regiis.exe -ir.

Comment: I tried this just as you said, running the developer command prompt in VS and navigating to that path, then running that command. No luck. No errors came up from running the command, but the API is still 403.14.

Comment: I suggest you could try to re-intall the asp.net 4.7  and IIS in the control panel and try again.

Comment: I tried this, and no luck. Also tried running microsoft's asp.net repair tool with no luck either. :(

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same problem.